# jquery move periodically left when reducing the margin

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, jquery

i want to create a animation. When i click some button the margin of my div will reduce and it will periodically move.

for example i have a

`<div style="margin-left:300px"></div>
  <button>Click to move div 100px to left</button>`

when i click the button, the margin will reduce while reducing it will periodically move to left. is there a animated code here for jquery??

to move periodically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('div').animate({'margin-left': '100px'}, 500);
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/amUw9/3/

See more at http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: glad to help. Pls Accept if the answer is useful :)